# Missing Time Travel feature on Apple Watch in OS3?

Tags: calendar, apple-watch

This was a feature I used frequently as I had my calendar on my watch, I would scroll a few hours ahead with the crown to see my next event easily without taking my phone out.

I looked quickly in the settings on the Watch app on the iPhone but could not see if it was buried in there.

Any one know if they removed this functionality completely?

Answer (score 5):

There's a toggle for Time Travel (the name of the feature you're talking about) in the Watch app on your iPhone. Turn this on to enable the feature.

Comment: Right, it's off by default in watchOS 3.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very intuitive setting on watchos 3.
Open the watch app on your iphone, go to notifications, clock, and turn on time travel, 
this is of course the most logical place to find this.

Alternatively: open the watch app, pull down to reveal the 'search settings' box, and type time travel.